# How to add plugin to shopware shop when vendor is too big?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have a problem with my plugin. I want to add it to Shopware shop but it has some composer dependencies and vendor folder have almost 70MB, after compressing 30MB. Shopware allows the vendor folder to have a maximum of 10MB.
Is there any solution of this problem? Can I add plugin in any other way without vendors?

I tried compress vendors but it's still too big.

Answer (score 2):

You mean the shopware store (for store.shopware.com)?
There is no other possibility. You might want to check the dependencies. What makes the vendor so big? Images?

In your Shopware shop you can upload/add whatever you want.